# Specifying "village, town" in QuickOSM plugin for QGIS?

Tags: quickosm

What to exactly enter for the "in" field? Let's say I want to query the data of a town called "Georgetown" in Colorado? What do I enter exactly? I've tried a bunch of combinations like "Georgetown, Colorado", but it doesn't retrieve the correct data.

[image]

Comment: The "in" statement is the same as the first result in https://osm.org. Do you mean this result is not correct ? https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Georgetown%2C%20Colorado#map=14/39.7186/-105.6954

Answer (score 2):

For **Georgetown, Co, US**
use the admin level (8)

[image]

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["admin_level"="8"]["name"="Georgetown"];
    way["admin_level"="8"]["name"="Georgetown"];
    relation["admin_level"="8"]["name"="Georgetown"];
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

Note this gets all Georgetowns - but you can filter by state as well or spatially.

Comment: Thanks, how do you search by state? Sounds obvious, but key=state and value=colorado results in: Successful query, but no result.

Comment: "value=colorado" can't be valid. I suggest you to read more about the OSM data model. States are represented by the key "admin_level" and value a number and the name with the key "name".